# Composer PSR-4 autoloading "class not found" debug

Tags: php, composer-php, autoloader, psr-4

Yes another question about the "class not found" error. Either I am missing something, or I misunderstood the PSR-4 logic.

My composer library directory sturcture:

"Scanner" => "src" => "Test.php"

Test.php

```
namespace MyNS;

class Test
{
}
```

composer.json

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyNS\\": "src/"
        },
}
```

So, now I load the library in my project with composer and try using it.

```
require_once("../vendor/autoload.php");

$test = new MyNS\Test();
```

Which always results in

> "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MyNS\Test' not found."

. What am I missing? I am staring at this for days now. I have changed folders, I have changed folder names, I have changed uppper to lower and vise versa. Nothing seems to work.

I am using PHP 7.2.2 and Composer version 1.2.2

Even tried this:

```
require_once("../vendor/autoload.php");

use MyNS\Test;

$scanner = new Test();
```

## Update

I debugt the Composer ClassLoader.php file (findFileWithExtension($class, $ext)) method and apparently my files are never loaded because I get put an echo "Done" and a die(); at the end of this method which means the file is not found and thus not loaded. What is wrong with my composer.json?

```
{
    "name": "test/test",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "",
    "keywords": ["php"],
    "homepage": "",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "email": "",
            "homepage": "",
            "role": ""
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2.2"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyNS\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the provided namespace, your path should be `src/PSR4/` and not `src/` and the namespace of class `Test` is `MyNS\PSR4` and not `MyNS` alone.

Comment: I removed PSR4 in the namespace (as mentioned) . Not working. I also moved Test.php to folder src/PSR4 and left namespace in tackt. Still not working.

Comment: Did you do `composer dump-autoload` after making changes?

Comment: It feels like that the autoloader isn't working at all. It doesn't seem to make a difference what names I use, what folders I use. I tried removing namespaces in both the classes and the composer.json.

Even that didn't work. It still returns 'Class not found'.

Comment: @revo yes everytime. Is there a way to debug what 'autoload' is exactly doing? In what folder it looks for what files for example?

Comment: can you post your full code on gists (https://gist.github.com/) so that it can be easier to monitor

Comment: @EmtiazZahid  

https://gist.github.com/digitalhuman/06bace6429cb6510bb531c50419de2b8
https://gist.github.com/digitalhuman/b97bf7e41150e5e6df885be18674f3b2

Comment: https://gist.github.com/digitalhuman/a95902020b0b9f7cf784ee9c7f2ebfeb

Answer (score 7):

To debug what is happening open `ClassLoader.php` file then go where `findFileWithExtension()` method is defined to add an `echo` statement:

```
# vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:386

foreach ($this->prefixDirsPsr4[$search] as $dir) {
    if (file_exists($file = $dir . $pathEnd)) {
        return $file;
    }
    // Add this line
    echo $file, PHP_EOL;
}
```

*Do not do `composer dumpautoload` after you manually modified above file until we are done.*

Now by executing your PHP file you will see something similar to this at the very beginning of output:

```
path/to/project/vendor/composer/../../src/Test.php
```

Which is:

```
path/to/project/src/Test.php
```

So this is the file that composer is looking for and should contain something like this:

```
namespace MyNS;

class Test { }
```

If there is an issue in including the file then it means you have to care about three things:

1. Path and filename
2. Namespace used in file
3. Class name used in file (class name should be the same as filename)

Comment: Thanks! I will do some testing later today. I'll keep you guys posted :)

Comment: 0 (zero) output. As my gut feeling said. It doesn't do anything with the psr-4 autoload.

Comment: So it never gets loaded by PSR-4. That is the conclusion. I debuged the entire findFileWithExtenson($class, $ext) method in the ClassLoader.php and it reaches the end of the method.

Comment: Please open up `autoload_psr4.php` and see the contents. Do you see a line corresponding to `MyNS`?

Comment: No I don't see anything except this:
`
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
);
`

Comment: thank for the tip, i am able to find the issue, i am with `psr-4`, so the file name of the class is matter, if you have a class named `Plugin`, then you have to name the file contains class as  `Plugin.php`, I encountered the issue several times when i switch back to PHP, I wonder if there is any tool we can debug the issue easier, eg: we have an autoload debug as a dev dependency, So we can run `autoload-check` to list all of loaded, unloaded files

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is in your namespace declaration

you calling the class from `MyNS` but class namespace is `namespace MyNS\PSR4;`

```
require_once("../vendor/autoload.php");

$test = new MyNS\Test();

// it should be new MyNS\PSR4\Test();
```

and make sure, your class file in same directory which you mentioned in `composer autoload` file

also you have to run `dump-autoload` command for any change in classnames

you can visit for this [autoload](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload-dumpautoload-) feature

Comment: I removed PSR4 in the namespace (as mentioned) . Not working. I also moved Test.php to folder src/PSR4 and left namespace in tact. Still not working.

Comment: after changing namespace did you run dump-autoload ? more details: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload-dumpautoload-